# Using templates in http sink in vector.dev

Tags: vectordotdev

I'm using vector.dev to send logs to Parseable. I need to send a header took from log event.
For example, if vector receive this log:

```
{
   "message":"Hello Vector!",
   "service":"education"
}
```

it should send header:

X-P-Stream: education

I tried to write in config:

```
request:
  headers:
    X-P-Stream: "{{ .service }}"
```

But it not works.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Templating in http sink's headers is currently not possible, see issue [vector#201](https://github.com/vectordotdev/vector/issues/201).

One way to achieve your result would be to create one sink in Vector per Parseable log stream and split your log source using [Route Transform](https://vector.dev/docs/reference/configuration/transforms/route/).